# Handle single quotes in a string

Tags: python

I am working with a binary that returns string in a python-ized list format:
e.g.:

```
"['BONE'N'T','me & me',]\n"
```

Now I want to translate this to a list, but this fails if I use eval, or ast.literal_eval

```
Error:
eval(s.strip("\n"))                                                                                                                                                                                 
 ***ERRORTRACEBACK***
   File "<string>", line 1
 ~     ['BONE'N'T','me & me',]
 ~            ^
 ~ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

 ********************

 ***ERROR*** <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>
 <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'> invalid syntax (<string>, line 1) []
```

I expect to get a list of strings, with the strings intact.

EDIT:
I managed to fixed it using:
sanitizing the list:
unsanitized_object_list.lstrip("[").rstrip(",]").split(",")

Then sanitizing every element in the list:
unsanitized_object_name.lstrip("'").rstrip("'")

It is ungraceful, and was hoping there is a more elegant solution :-)

Comment: This `'BONE'N'T'` is not a valid Python string, note that it has single quotes inside single quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion escaping single quotes in a single-quoted raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045675/confusion-escaping-single-quotes-in-a-single-quoted-raw-string-literal)

Comment: I am not looking for a description of the problem, but a resolution. I understand that the string is not a valid python string. Is there a way to perhaps change the outer quotes to double, or escape the ones in the name?

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because your example is not valid syntax for a Python list. If `'BONE'N'T'` is supposed to be a single list item, you will need to escape the quotes inside the string.

```
>>> eval("['BONE\\'N\\'T','me & me',]")
["BONE'N'T", 'me & me']
```

Comment: as described. the binary returns the string in that format.

Comment: If the expected output is an array of strings, and none of those strings contain commas, you could do something like `[token.strip(' \'') for token in data.strip('\r\n[]').split(',')]` where `data` is the output of your binary. Without some constraints, the problem seems too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a good enough solution:

[token.strip(' \'') for token in data.strip('\r\n[]').split(',')]